# How to run PyCharm remotely, using a local version of PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-access

Does PyCharm provide an option of remotely modifying a python program and running it on a different server, which for itself runs a full version of PyCharm?

If I want to simulate this process without PyCharm, what I would do is: Edit the code locally or use vim+ssh, and then run ssh+python. I want to have a GUI-based and far more efficient way of doing this. Does anybody know if PyCharm is capable of that?

So what I imagine is: Editing .py files locally and when I choose to run them, they would run in the PyCharm of the server side Additionally, it would be great to have the option that when there is a figure for matplotlib, the server side passes the figure to the client side to display it. Maybe this is too much to ask but I imagine it is very handy!

I figured out "deployment", but as far as I realised, deployment assumes that the remote server does not have PyCharm and starts installing everything again on the server so that the python on server side have the necessary libraries. Any clues?

Comment: [This is a related feature request for PyCharm.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752)

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately pycharm has ssh plugin that you can clone server file , editing localy then sync with server by sftp protocol

**Edit**

In menu *Tools->Deployment->configuration* add sftp server and login with putty user and pass. The next steps are obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you mean the server side also has the PyCharm or not? What I am looking for is to be able to do everything on the PyCharm of the local device and all the execution to happen on the server side.

Comment: The server side must support ssh and sftp protocol.

Comment: @Cupitor. Did that suggestion work for you? I'm using PyCharm Community Edition and I don't see _Tools->Deployment_ option. Were you using Professional Editiion?

Comment: Yes i am using PyCharm Full Version